# Host WCF in Windows server 2008 R2 and IIS7.5

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-server-2008

After I deployed WCF web service to Windows server 2008 R2, I was able to have a page at "http://192.168.100.22:4567/HrmsService.svc" This works on the server, but not on my PC.
I created a windows form application and I tried add it as service reference, but there is on error message like below. I installed VS2010 on the server , and I tried to add it as service reference and it works for windows form application. I even added port 4567 in the server firewall to allow it.
I tried for all this morning, but I could not figure out. Please, let me know.

> Error Message
>
> There was an error downloading
> 'http://192.168.100.22:4567/HrmsService.svc?wsdl'. Unable to connect
> to the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
> 192.168.100.22:4567 Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://192.168.100.22:4567/HrmsService.svc?wsdl'. There was
> no endpoint listening at
> 'http://192.168.100.22:4567/HrmsService.svc?wsdl' that could accept the
> message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
> See InnerException, if present, for more details. Unable to connect to
> the remote server A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
> 192.168.100.22:4567 If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

This is my Web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"><assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /></assemblies></compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
          <service name="WcfServiceHrms.HrmsService" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorHrms">
              <endpoint address= ""  binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceHrms.IHrmsService" />
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
               <host>
                   <baseAddresses>
                       <add baseAddress="http://192.168.100.22:4567" />
                  </baseAddresses>
              </host>
          </service>
      </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehaviorHrms">
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% that this error is related to network configuration and has nothing to do with WCF.

Try telnet 192.168.100.22 4567

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx

Move your service to port 80. Not standard ports are often closed by firewalls.

Comment: You were 100% correct. I changed it port 80 and it worked out. But I am wondering why I need to only use port 80. Is it true or is there any other way to use other port number? BTW, thanks for your help.

Comment: Port 80 is default port for HTTP and usually open in any network. You need to talk to your networking team to figure-out your company policies.